# Java source directories for Android Studio project flavors not rendered in blue

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have an Android Gradle project and I want to create two flavor branches. I'm use the default sourceSets with this structure:

```
src
  - main
    - java
      - package   
    - res
    - manifest.xml

  - flavor1
    - java
      - package

  - flavor2
    - java
      - package
```

"main/java", "flavor1/java" is rendered/annotated as Java source in the IDE (i.e., "java" is in blue, and the directories are shown as packages), but "flavor2" is not rendered the same way.

I tried to clear the caches and restart Android Studio but this did not help. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your main directory (content root) sources will always be blue colored by default, but others depend on the activeness.

The blue color directory shows that the build variant or content root is active and if you will use the `Run` button of IDE, it will take these sources to compile and build you app. Only one content root can be active at a time for building the app.

You can change and make any directory/flavor active for your content root to compile and build your app when run option is used. It can be done from **`Build Variants`** tab available in left panel of your Android Studio.

Like shown in picture below :

**Production is active here:**

[image: prodmark]

**uat is active here:**

[image: uatmark]

Comment: I need to mark some directories as source, and some as test in non-standard for Android Studio in a imported in AS old project. But what was available in Idea, not accessible in AS. Could i mark dirs as i want in AS?

Comment: This behavior of AS is annoying. If the build flavor is not active, it is impossible to right click the `java` folder and do `New > Package` or `New > Java Class`...

Comment: @Sébastien I agree, Also already written java files won't be considered as JAVA so while editing they won't give you code suggestions etc.

Answer (score 9):

Based on user pyus13 's answer I found that by going to build variants and simply selecting flavor2release in your case, the folder becomes blue.

So by clicking the release version of the flavor you want to make active the folder becomes blue.

Hope this helps. Thanks pyus13!