# Android Studio - Gradle assemble task

Tags: android-studio, gradle, task, android-productflavors

I'm currently struggling with a build process in gradle. My goal is to not have a specific java class in the final .apk for a specific flavor.
The logic goes like this:

1.) before compiling my project delete MyClass.java and copy it to a temp folder

2.) after assembling the apk copy back MyClass.java to my original folder

3.) delete the temp folder

This happens only if I build a specific flavor, so it doesn't happen for all build variants. My code works perfectly when I build only one flavor and one build variant e.g. assembleFlavorRelease, but if I wan't to make my code work for multiple build types; if I run assembleFlavor it should build flavorDebug the same way it does flavorRelease. 
However my logic goes trough only the first time and after that it stops, so flavorDebug is build with MyClass and it shouldn't be, while flavorRelease doesn't include MyClass in the .apk because my code runs the first time.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
task copyResource << {
    copy {
        from 'src/main/java/MyClass.java'
        into 'src/temp'
    }
}

task deleteResource << {
    delete {
        'src/main/java/MyClass.java'
    }
}

task deleteTemp << {
    delete {
        'src/temp'
    }
}

task copyBackToSource << {
    copy {
        from 'src/temp/MyClass.java'
        into 'src/main/java'
    }
    deleteTemp.execute()
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.name.contains('flavor')) {
        deleteResource.dependsOn copyResource
        variant.javaCompile.dependsOn deleteResource
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            copyBackToSource.execute()
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the directories which I use in my code are somehow locked when trying to execute the whole process the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you are approaching the problem in the wrong way. Instead of thinking

> Put the java file in src/main/java and remove it from flavorX

You should instead be approaching it as

> Add an extra source directory to the source sets for flavorY and flavorZ

Once you approach the problem like this it becomes much easier

If you only want the file in one flavor, you can put the file in the flavor specific source folder using the built in conventions (ie `src/flavorX/java`)

If you want the file in more than one flavor you could put MyClass.java in `src/common/java` and do something like

```
android {
   productFlavors {
       flavor1 {
       }
       flavor2 {
       }
       flavor3 {
       }
   }
}
sourceSets {
    flavor1.java = ['src/flavor1/java','src/common/java']
    flavor2.java = ['src/flavor2/java','src/common/java']
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am aware of this kind of solution. The problem is that my app structure is complex and I have 7 different flavors, which means I would have to duplicate MyClass.java several times in the src of flavors that include it, plus the flavor src structure isn't visible in Android Studio under android view as I am aware. I want to avoid this solution and I prefer my solution for my app structure. I there any other way to exclude specific class?

Comment: "which means I would have to duplicate MyClass.java several times" is incorrect. I gave two solutions, one if you needed the file in a single flavor, the other which included a single source directory two or more flavors without duplication of the source file. "plus the flavor src structure isn't visible in Android Studio under android view as I am aware" I'd be surprised if that was the case.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, you are right, i could put the class in common. I tried that before but as i said it is not nicely visible in the project structure and it produces some other problems. I posted the correct solution below which is clean and works nicely.

Comment: I'd argue that your solution is dirty rather than clean :P. Imagine if MyClass.java required an additional dependency

Comment: If I use your option the src which is flavor specific is not visible in AndroidStudio under Android view, which is just one problem among others.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697565/android-studio-project-with-flavors-sources-directory-not-shown-in-blue-color) to activate a flavor in android studio

Comment: Above link shows a "Project" view which is not an "Android". Anyways if I use src for flavors it produces an error when building it, because of dependancy.

Comment: I recently experienced some problems with the way I was excluding single files. I ditched this method and went with your concept, which solved my problem.

Comment: Great! Did you manage to make the source 'visible' in AndroidStudio?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did yes, though the classes are now visible, they are not in the same package structure, but it's not such a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got the right solution from here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-gradle-assemble-tasks/10711

If you want to avoid compiling a specific class then use this:

```
variant.javaCompile.exclude '**/SourceFileToExclude.java'
```

Comment: As I said, in my opinion this is the wrong way to tackle the problem. Single file excludes are nasty. Additive source sets are much easier to maintain (think of the next poor sod looking at the code).

Comment: In my case it performs better. I marked your answer as useful, although I can't mark it as an answer to my question. I appreciate your help.